# high voltage coil protection with epoxy resin

Tags: power-electronics, inductor, coil

I have a high voltage cylinder coil with iron core. I want to protect it with epoxy resin. What is a good and easy way to do it for single use in a lab environment? What are the pitfalls?

Comment: Protect it from what?

Comment: What makes you think that your protecting the high voltage coil if the breakdown of the epoxy is lower than your transformer, if it isn't you could get arcing through the epoxy

Comment: thank you for your answer. How can I know breakdown voltage is lower or not? It is not a transformer.

Comment: High Voltage is not a domain for a do-it-yourselfer.  Human life is at stake.  Hire a professional.

Comment: It is not for commercial or professional work. It is for a lab test

Answer (score 1):

Not enough info.

What "high voltage?" 500V? 200KV?  Are your windings on a plastic spool?  Are you embedding the core as well (and why iron, rather than ferrite for high-freq?)

Many-kilovolts HV protection is usually via silicone rubber casting with hardner (2-part silicone liquid,) not epoxy.  Can't remove epoxy to inspect a failed coil, at least not easily.

Look up the "dielectric" rating for your epoxy, volts/mil breakdown, etc.   Buy "high-dielectric" epoxy.   Or get castable liquid silicone rubber for HV encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Flyback coils like TV or automotive ignition coils may be capable of 35kV. They often fail due to environmental dust and moisture or "surface creepage" contamination. To restore that performance *to avoid external corona*   requires removal of "all" ionic material.

Coating with liquid rubber, silicone or epoxy may increase it's insulation if the magnet wire windings of insulation are OK and the surface is very clean without ionic residue.